# Rename a file dynamically containing spaces

Tags: shell, rename, filenames

I want to rename a file dynamically based on data which contains spaces

```
Name="Abc DEF"
Name1="GHI JKL"

mv /sample/pdf/noriginalName.pdf /sample/outputPdf/${NAME}${Name1}".pdf"
```

But it gives me an error because it encounters space in between.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is it `Name` or `NAME`?

Answer (score 5):

Don't worry, you're not the first and won't be the last one to be bitten by that. It's the most frequently asked question about shells, and that's responsible for most bugs and security vulnerabilities found in shell scripts. That's due to a bad design choice of the Bourne shell and the Korn shell in the earlier Unix history.

In the Bourne shell and most of its descendants (ksh, ash, pdksh, mksh, bash, dash, yash...), leaving a variable unquoted is the split+glob operator.

Best demonstrated with:

```
$ var='*.txt,.*'
$ IFS=',' # default is space tab and newline
$ printf '<%s>\n' $var
<file.txt>
<.>
<..>
```

The shell has split `$var` on `,`  characters and expanded each of the resulting words (which in this case contain wildcard characters) in the list of files matching the corresponding pattern.

### That's why, in Bourne-like shells (except `zsh`), you **must** always quote your variables (unless you do want the *split* and/or *glob*)

```
$ printf '<%s>\n' "$var"
<*.txt:.*>
```

So in your case:

```
mv /sample/pdf/noriginalName.pdf "/sample/outputPdf/${NAME}${Name1}.pdf"
```

or:

```
mv /sample/pdf/noriginalName.pdf /sample/outputPdf/"${NAME}${Name1}".pdf
```

(where you put the quotes doesn't  matter as long as the variables are quoted).

You can disable the splitting only with:

```
IFS=
```

And you can disable the globbing only with:

```
set -f # affects all globbing, not only the one done upon variable expansion.
```

With:

```
IFS=; set -f
```

You get the same behaviour as `zsh` for parameter expansion, no globbing, no splitting. You still need to quote your variable however in

```
cmd "$var"
```

If you want `cmd` to be passed *one* empty argument  when `$var` is empty or unset (as opposed to *no* argument at all). A typical example is `[ -n "$var" ]` where if you don't quote `$var`, the test will alway be true since when `$var` is empty, that resolves to `[ -n ]` instead of `[ -n '' ]`.

In `zsh`, globbing and splitting is not done implicitly upon variable expansion (except in `sh` or `ksh` emulation mode). You have to request it explicitly using specific expansion operators: `$=var` for word splitting, `$~var` for globbing (or `${~var}`; `$~=var` for both).

The other shells that don't have this kind of problem are `fish`, and `rc` and its descendants (`es`, `akanga`).

In `(t)csh`:

```
cmd "$var"
```

helps but is not enough, as it doesn't work if `$var` contains newline characters. There, you need:

```
cmd $var:q
```

Answer (score 4):

You must quote the whole file name:

```
mv /sample/pdf/noriginalName.pdf "/sample/outputPdf/${NAME}${Name1}.pdf"
```

Using double quote prevent `bash` and other Bourne-like shells (except `zsh`) perform [Field  splitting](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05) after your variable is expanded.